# SSRS 2012 nullable hidden parameter

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a report that pulls data from an xml datasource, populates a parameter with a value, then uses this in the next dataset.

The problem I have is that, despite VS allowing me to set the parameter as nullable, SSRS report manager will not. There is no checkbox.

When running the report I get

> The parameter is missing as value

This occurs when there is no value returned by the xml dataset, resulting in a null (valid for the report).

I have tried creating a second parameter, then basing this off the first

```
Param2 = iif(isnothing(Parameters!Param1.Value,0,Parameters!Param1.Value)
```

This works fine in VS, but not once deployed to SSRS

Any thoughts, wise people?

Comment: There's no "Allow null value" in the parameter settings? Is this a multi-value parameter?

Comment: @RigertaDemiri Multi-Value is not selected. Dataset can only return 1 value

Comment: I believe you need to add few example screenshots so that one can understand what is actually going on?